# GWT ServleContext and retrieving a file

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on a GWT application, and I'm trying to retrieve the file from "war/config/config.properties". In GWT server side I made a class called Config.java which creates a new Properties object and populates it from config.properties, I've extended Config with RemoteServiceServlet to be able to use getServletContext(). I am using the following line to load the properties

```
prop.load(ServletContext.class.getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties"));
```

and my config.properties file looks like this

```
database=db
host=192.168.1.1
password=pass
user=user
```

and my config class looks like this

```
public class Config extends RemoteServiceServlet {

Properties prop = new Properties();

public Config(){
    //load a properties file
    try {           
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();            
        prop.load(sc.getResource("/config/config.properties").openStream());

        //System.out.println("Get Real Path" + getServletContext().getRealPath("config") + "/config.properties");
        //FileInputStream input = (FileInputStream) getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties");
        //prop.load(new FileInputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/config/config.properties")));
        //prop.load(input);
        System.out.println("properties file loaded successfully");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Could not find properties file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("null pointer exception in loading properties file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getProperty(String name){
    return prop.getProperty(name);
}

}
```

and yet for the life of me I can't figure out why I'm getting a null pointer exception when I am loading properties, simply refuses to work. Stack trace is here, any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.cbs.ioma.server.Config.<init>(Config.java:19)
    at com.cbs.ioma.server.DatabaseServiceImpl.<init>(DatabaseServiceImpl.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)``
```

edit: I changed my code to reflect a comment below, new error is posted here

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:160)
>   at com.cbs.ioma.server.Config.<init>(Config.java:19)
```

edit: I changed my class, could you take a look and tell me how I'm supposed to call the servlet? I don't get how I'm supposed to override the method, if its called by another method in Servlet. how do I implement it?

```
public class Config extends RemoteServiceServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    public Config(){

    }

    public String getProperty(String name){
        return prop.getProperty(name);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        super.init(config);
        try {           
            prop.load(config.getServletContext().getResource("/config/config.properties").openStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread your question. If the file is in `war/config/config.properties`, you should use

```
ServletContext sc = ...// get servlet context; 
sc.getResource("/config/config.properties");
```

as described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a URL to the resource that is mapped to a specified path. The
>   path must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the
>   current context root.

**Edit**

When a `Servlet` container starts up, it instantiates your `Servlet` (`Config` for you) class using the no-args constructor. It then calls its [`Servlet#init(ServletConfig)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method where you can finally have access to the `ServletContext`. This is where you should initialize your `Properties` object. So override the method and move your current constructor code to it.

---

For your information

Don't do this

```
ServletContext.class.getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties")
```

If `config/config.properties` is at the root of the classpath, use

```
ServletContext.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties")
```

The top case will take the name of the package that `ServletContext` is in and try to resolve your specified path with it. For example, `ServletContext` is in `javax.servlet`, so

```
/javax/servlet/config/config.properties
```

Your resource is clearly not in there. The rules for what path you should specify are described in the [javadoc of `Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: it looks like you copied and pasted the same thing?

Comment: wait I see the change, the /. I did try that as well, still no dice.

Comment: Also if it couldn't find the file wouldn't it give me a file not found exception first?

Comment: @john I misunderstood your question. See my edit. It wouldn't give a `FileNotFoundException` because it isn't looking for a `File`, it's looking for a resource as a URL.

Comment: Hm this still wouldn't work because sc.getResource() provides a URL while prop.load() is looking for a InputStream, is there a a way to use getResourceAsStream instead?

Comment: @john Yes, `ServletContext` has such a method or you can call `openStream()` on the `URL`.

Comment: Ah 'openStream()' works to get it to work with prop. Still having issues with getting it to work, same error each time.

Comment: @john Can you edit in the new code. I don't know what `RemoteServiceServlet`is  but it doesn't seem like you've set the `ServletContext` anywhere.

Comment: @john Ok the problem is that the `ServletConfig` required to get the `SerlvetContext` is not available in the constructor. The `Servlet` container only provides it in the `init(ServletConfig)` method. Override it and do your properties loading in there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, is there any way you can post an example of what you explained?

Comment: @John See my edit. You cannot use your constructor to access the `ServletContext`.

Comment: @Sotirious Delimanolis Can you please see my edit to the question above and comment on how to implement it? I'm sorry but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this concept, it's not coming very easy.

Comment: @john What you are doing now seems fine to me (first look). Are you still getting an exception? If yes, please post it too.

Comment: @Sotirious Delimanolis Well I'm not sure how to implement this? Since I never call `getServletContext()` in my config file, my override method never gets called.

Comment: If i create a config object in another class, it has a `Properties` object but that object never loads anything.

Comment: @john You shouldn't be creating `Config` objects. They are `Servlet` instances. The `Servlet` container should be creating them.

Comment: @Sotrious Delimanolis How do I call a `Servlet` instance? can you give me a sample line I can use in another class?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use a higher level library to  take care of that for you.

For example use `ResourceBundle`

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(fully.qualified.path.using.dots.to.properties);
bundle.getString("your_property_key");
```

Comment: hey manubot, I tried using Constants, but you aren't allowed to use it server side unless you use a 3rd helper class.

Comment: @john you are right, sorry. Constants are not usable on server, I'll edit the answer. But ResourceBundle should do the job for you (it does for me)

Comment: can you give an example of the fully qualified path? 'getservletcontext' still isn't work for me.

Comment: @john You don't need calling getservletcontext when using the ressource bundle. I think the issue is that you are looking at the .properties as a file on a fileserver when they are part of your classpath and you should see them as just another class (for the porpuses of ResourceBundle). You need to have the properties in your classpath and use a qualified name like "com.myapp.server.ressources.myproperties.properties"